# Why are my folders suddenly not writable? (CSG operation error Meshlab 2020.03)

Tags: meshlab

I installed Meshlab 2020.03 in two different computers. I could do CSG operations just fine the very first time after installing it.
Once I reopen Meshlab to do the exact same operation with the same STL files, I get this error message:

*Failure of filter: "CSG Operation"
current folder is not writable.
CSG needs to save intermidiate files in the current working folder.
Project and meshes mush be in a write-enables folder.
Please save your dara in a suitable folder before applying.*

I haven't changed anything regarding the files, in fact, I can operate them in with other softwares. And the folder permits are enabled. I also tried relocating the files, but keep getting the same message (on 2 different computers)

Any guidance on why this could happen? Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error too lately. You can fix this issue by removing unreferenced vertices under the filter-> Cleaning and Repairing tab.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but doesn't solve it for me. Funny thing is I can operate everything properly when I reinstall the program, but reopening it gives me the error.

I reinstalled the 2016v which doesn't give me any issues. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when running "Surface Reconstruction: VCG"

"VCG Merging needs to save intermediate files in the current working folder. Project and meshes must be in a write-enabled folder."

I found something here which helped me.
https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/621#issuecomment-604093523

On my Mac with Meshlab 2021.10 I used terminal to launch meshlab from my working directory. Then it worked like it should.

```
workspace % /Applications/MeshLab2021.10.app/Contents/MacOS/meshlab
```

I was also able to get a segmentation fault messing around with the VCG settings.